# Example of $\infty$ functor on representation not being right exact

Tags: number-theory, representation-theory, topological-groups

[image]
[image]

> I need an counter example showing that $\infty$ is not right exact, that is, an example that for an exact sequence of $G$-homomorphisms of $G$-spaces(not necessarily smooth): $$0\rightarrow U \rightarrow V\rightarrow W\rightarrow 0$$
>
> We have $V^{\infty}\rightarrow W^{\infty}\rightarrow 0$ not exact.

Basically I have trouble even finding a non-trivial exact sequence to work with due to lack of experience, help please.

Comment: How is this question related to number theory?

Comment: Smooth representations of reductive $p$-adic groups!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any ($\mathbb C[G]$-equivariant) quotient map $V\to W$ gives a short exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow U \rightarrow V\rightarrow W\rightarrow 0$$
where $U$ is the kernel. So what you need to show is that $\cdot^{\infty}$ does not preserve epimorphisms.

For any abstract group $G$ there is an epimorphism of left $\mathbb C[G]$-modules
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb C[G]&\rightarrow \mathbb C \\
\sum z_g e_g&\mapsto\sum z_g
\end{align*}$$
where $\mathbb C[G]$ is the left regular rep and $\mathbb C$ has the trivial action. If you take any non-discrete locally profinite group $G$ then $\cdot^{\infty}$ will map this epimorphism to $0\rightarrow \mathbb C$.